# Getting weird border

Tags: wpf

Im not able to under stand why there is a black Border in the end. Below Cancel button. im not sure why this kind of behavior is occurring.as im not able to pin point my problem.(I did check my code many times) im attach that solution it self please take a look. thanks

[image: If u see bottom border its kinda gray clr]
[Code is here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nI2iWhSatQ6ttRQsiBpPDA6sOXc0HpNt)

Comment: Please dont close it

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to replicate?"  Also, you should post the code - few people are going to open links like that

Comment: Also, what is the desired behavior?  Should the red box not be there?

Comment: Ok, you should clarify that in the question.  I assumed it was about the red box.  So you've copy and pasted **all** of the code into an new project and it doesn't occur?

Comment: Well, compare the two projects and see what's different

Comment: "Except some styling" - so likely that.  Again, if you don't post code, you won't get help.

Comment: Ok, then I have to vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without pixel snapping, anti-aliased rendered lines may appear blurry if the edge falls between device pixels.

I have had the same problem in the past. I solved it by adding `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"` to the application's root element: [SnapsToDevicePixels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.snapstodevicepixels?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_UIElement_SnapsToDevicePixels)

```
    mc:Ignorable="d" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"   WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
```

Comment: that was the problem thank you for taking your time and checking it.

Comment: [`UseLayoutRounding="True"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.uselayoutrounding?view=netframework-4.8) on the root element would achieve the same effect.